# React TypeError: location is undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, mern

I am currently working on creating a boilerplate react application. I have been following [these](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuNEz8XtB51KthRFiVtI8cmXNL9qlQJ5U) tutorials, but I haven't been able to get past the first tutorial.

I created my app with create-react-app

When I try to run my app, it compiles, but I get an error that says:
TypeError: location is undefined

This error points to the ReactDOM.render( line in this code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';


ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

If it is relevant, here is my app.js file as well

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { HomePage, LoginPage } from "./components/pages";
import { Grid } from 'react-flexbox-grid';
import 'react-flexbox-grid/dist/react-flexbox-grid.css';

const App = () => (
  <Grid fluid>
    <Route path='/' exact component={HomePage} />
    <Route path='/login' exact component={LoginPage} />
  </Grid>
)

export default App;
```

I've also tried creating a new react app. For the first time, I ejected the app so that I could add css modules, then when I tried to build it again, I used custom react scripts. The problem began about when I ejected the app, but I'm sure if that was the problem because I did rebuild it and copy the src folder over to the new app.

Finally, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huSW6.png) is a screenshot of the errors that I am getting.

I've been stuck on this problem for the past 2.5 days, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

**UPDATE:** Hey guys. I'm an idiot. The `<Link>` component uses a `to` attribute unlike the `a` tag's `href`. That was my problem. Really. Well there goes 3 days down the drain and all of your time. Thank you for your help anyway, I appreciate all that you have done.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error you're getting is because the renderer can't find the "root" dom element to hook into.  Do you have a <div id="root"/> in the html file you are sourcing your js source-code?

Comment: I do have a <div id="root"></div> in the html file already. Is there anything else that could stop it from running?

Comment: Where is `location` being used in the app? Any `location` variables, props, etc?

Comment: I've already looked through everything I wrote. I don't think I've used the word location anywhere.

Comment: Did you install the `react-router` package?

Comment: Location is a part of the React 16 Routing API: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route  I'm sorry I don't have an answer yet, but I'm looking into it.

Comment: Btw, the link to the youtube tutorial has errors in it: "hhttps//www"

Comment: Yes I have `react router` installed. I will also look into the API. And I fixed the link. Thank you all so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: Hey guys. I'm an idiot. The  component uses a to attribute unlike the a tag's href. That was my problem. Really. Well there goes 3 days down the drain and all of your time. Thank you for your help anyway, I appreciate all that you have done.

Comment: LOL... So the issue was not in any of the code that you had posted... Yes, it's Link to...

Comment: Yeah. I feel really silly. I'm just happy that I fixed it.

Comment: Well, congrats on solving your problem. :)  No problem at all about the time spent.  This is how we learn and get better.  We'll know better for the next time.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT - Explanation of the Resolution** (as described in @Vishah's answer)

I'm adding an edit here in hopes of helping anyone who comes across this.

The source of the issue was the Links components included "href" attributes instead of "to" attributes.

```
-        <Link href='/'>Home</Link>
+        <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
```

Additionally, it's worth noting the "href" didn't throw an attribute error because lowercase attributes are still valid dom in React ^16.2.

Here's the commit on his repo: https://github.com/vishalmshah/MERNStackBoilerplate/commit/73fb3fe2e39ffa870fb91bd8b3592887886e3dbb

---

**This was not the source of the issue**

I think I see the issue.  BrowserRouter uses the location object to keep track of where you are, your history, and possibly other locations the app will navigate to.

BrowserRouter Routes require being given location object which they can use to compare their path value to.

You've got your Route's wrapped by your App object without passing the location object down.

Try passing location through your app:

```
const App = ({ location }) => (
```

Subsequently you may have to access the location in the Routes:

```
<Route location={location} ...
```

This example is where I got the information from:
https://github.com/Remchi/bookworm-react/blob/master/src/App.js

Comment: I just added that to my code, but it did not work. I'm assuming that you meant passing location by doing this:
`const App = ({ location }) => (
  <div>
    <Route location={location} path='/' exact component={HomePage} />
    <Route location={location} path='/login' exact component={LoginPage} />
  </div>
)`

Is that what you meant or should I do something else. Also, [this](https://github.com/Remchi/bookworm-react/tree/9d4807b28e9c430376ba0d68c3e44eed506f19ea) is what the code looked like at the end of the first tutorial. There is not location there.

Comment: Gotcha.  Yeah, that was my intent.  Would you mind supplying me with the version of the app you're working with?  I can't finish this now, but I'll take a look later and see if I can't figure it out.

Comment: [Here is a link to my github repo](https://github.com/vishalmshah/MERNStackBoilerplate). I just created one. Anyway, thank you so much for helping me out. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I notice immediately is how you are importing the components...

```
import { HomePage, LoginPage } from "./components/pages";
```

You can not do this... Instead:

```
import HomePage from './components/pages/HomePage';
import LoginPage from './components/pages/LoginPage';
```

Also, you should not install react-router but just react-router-dom...

Here is the App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './HomePage';
import LoginPage from './LoginPage';

const App = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={HomePage} exact={true} />
    <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} exact={true} />
  </Switch>
);

export default App;
```

And here is the Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './components/App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

Note: I did not create the pages directory and am also using Switch... (docs: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch)

Comment: I'm able to use import { blah, blah } because I have an index.js file that exports each component in each directory. 

I'm also currently following a tutorial, but my preferred structure for my components would be a layout, container, and presentation directory, so I can organize my work. I plan on changing that later.

I did not realize that I didn't need react-router, so thank you for letting me know. I like to keep things light and simple.

Finally, I have changed the div to Switch, but, unfortunately, it did not work. 

Anyway, I just put my code on Github, Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you post the link to the repo?

Comment: Oh, sorry. [Here's](https://github.com/vishalmshah/MERNStackBoilerplate) the link. Forgot to add it.